# Getting all variants in a region from ensembl

Tags: ensembl, variation, api

I want to get all the variants (SNPs) in a given region of the human genome. Is there a way on how to do this with the ensembl-API? It should be a representation similar to this: [image]

There I added dbSNP to the region details. Having this data in a JSON or XML-Format would be really helpful! [Here](http://www.ensembl.org/Homo_sapiens/Location/View?db=core;r=11:108290588-108290689;source=dbSNP;v=rs1491549802;vdb=variation;vf=595960779;time=1625753581)'s the link to the image.

Edit: I know that the export-function on ensembl is a thing. But then I only get the rs-Numbers. To get all the info I need I would have to run (potentially thousands) all the rs-Numbers through some additional API. Getting that info in bulk right away would be a huge time-saver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[REST API overlap region endpoint](http://rest.ensembl.org/documentation/info/overlap_region). [For example](https://rest.ensembl.org/overlap/region/human/11:108290588-108290689?feature=variation;content-type=application/json).

Comment: Thats exaclty what I need! Thanks Emily!